# Flutter/Dart Class Instance and Class Variable

Tags: class, flutter, variables, dart, class-variables

I am new to dart and am having issues storing data in a class. I know how to create instances but I then want to store each instance into a map that I can easily access. Here is my code below...

```
class myCar{
  var myMapOfCars = new Map(); // I wanted this to be a class level variable that I can continuously add or remove from. 

  String carName; // Instance

  myCar({this.carName});

  addInfoToMap() {
    // Some logic to increment the index or create the index the 

    myMapOfCars[theKey]  = this.carName; // This should be the class variable.

  }
}
```

Every time I call "addInfoToMap", the "myMapOfCars" instance is reinitialized and empty again. I wanted to add/append into the map so I can have as many cars in there as I want. I am open to other solutions as well, I come from Swift and I know you can do it in Swift. It just makes everything really clean.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods

Comment: That's it. Thought I had tried that but I guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation "[Class variables and methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods)" would be appropriate for this.

> Static variables
> Static variables (class variables) are useful for class-wide state and
> constants:
>
> ```
> class Queue {
>   static const initialCapacity = 16;
>   // ···
> }
>
> void main() {
>   assert(Queue.initialCapacity == 16);
> }
> ```
>
> Static variables aren’t initialized until they’re used.

> Static methods
> Static methods (class methods) don’t operate on an instance, and thus
> don’t have access to this. They do, however, have access to static
> variables. As the following example shows, you invoke static methods
> directly on a class:
>
> ```
> import 'dart:math';
>
> class Point {
>   double x, y;
>   Point(this.x, this.y);
>
>   static double distanceBetween(Point a, Point b) {
>     var dx = a.x - b.x;
>     var dy = a.y - b.y;
>     return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
>   }
> }
>
> void main() {
>   var a = Point(2, 2);
>   var b = Point(4, 4);
>   var distance = Point.distanceBetween(a, b);
>   assert(2.8 < distance && distance < 2.9);
>   print(distance);
> }
> ```
>
> You can use static methods as compile-time constants. For example, you
> can pass a static method as a parameter to a constant constructor.

As an additional reference, you can also visit [this blog](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fluttering-dart-oop-8b92cd89a7f0).